# How to show multiple icons above same bar in charts swift

Tags: swift, charts, mpandroidchart

I am using CHARTS library in Swift. https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts

currently plotting barchart using sample value with icons using the following code

```
barValue = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i.x!), y: Double(y), icon: UIImage(named: "xIcon"))
```

by doing this my chart is plotted but when I add two values at the same point bar chart show icons overlapping and what I want is to have icon on the same bar like one icon on top of another.

Current result:

[image]

Expected:

[image]